# Counting the number of lines having a number greater than 100

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a file with many numbers in it (only numbers and each number is in one line). I want to find out the number of lines in which the number is greater than 100 (or infact anything else). How can I do that?

Answer (score 13):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat myfile
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
```

Now, let's count the number of lines with a number greater than 100:

```
$ awk '$1>100{c++} END{print c+0}' myfile
5
```

#### How it works

- `$1>100{c++}`

  Every time that the number on the line is greater than 100, the variable `c` is incremented by 1.
- `END{print c+0}`

  After we have finished reading the file, the variable `c` is printed.

  By adding `0` to `c`, we force awk to treat `c` like a number.  If there were any lines with numbers `>100`, then `c` is already a number.  If there were not, then `c` would be an empty (hat tip: [iruvar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21233/iruvar)).  By adding zero to it, we change the empty string to a `0`, giving a more correct output.

Comment: I would change the `print c` to `print 0+c` or even `print +c` so a sane value of 0 is printed when no line exists with a number greater than `100`

Comment: @iruvar Good point!  Thanks. answer updated with `+0` to force conversion to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution with `perl`

```
$ seq 98 105 | perl -ne '$c++ if $_ > 100; END{print $c+0 ."\n"}'
5
```

**Speed comparison:** numbers reported for 3 consecutive runs

Random file:

```
$ perl -le 'print int(rand(200)) foreach (0..10000000)' > rand_numbers.txt
$ perl -le 'print int(rand(100200)) foreach (0..10000000)' >> rand_numbers.txt

$ shuf rand_numbers.txt -o rand_numbers.txt 
$ tail -5 rand_numbers.txt 
114
100
66125
84281
144
$ wc rand_numbers.txt 
20000002 20000002 93413515 rand_numbers.txt
$ du -h rand_numbers.txt 
90M rand_numbers.txt
```

With `awk`

```
$ time awk '$1>100{c++} END{print c+0}' rand_numbers.txt 
14940305

real    0m7.754s
real    0m8.150s
real    0m7.439s
```

With `perl`

```
$ time perl -ne '$c++ if $_ > 100; END{print $c+0 ."\n"}' rand_numbers.txt 
14940305

real    0m4.145s
real    0m4.146s
real    0m4.196s
```

And just for fun with `grep` (**Updated**: faster than even Perl with LC_ALL=C)

```
$ time grep -xcE '10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2,}|1[0-9]{3,}' rand_numbers.txt 
14940305

real    0m10.622s

$ time LC_ALL=C grep -xcE '10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2,}|1[0-9]{3,}' rand_numbers.txt
14940305

real    0m0.886s
real    0m0.889s
real    0m0.892s
```

`sed` is no fun:

```
$ time sed -nE '/^10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2,}|1[0-9]{3,}$/p' rand_numbers.txt | wc -l
14940305

real    0m11.929s

$ time LC_ALL=C sed -nE '/^10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2,}|1[0-9]{3,}$/p' rand_numbers.txt | wc -l
14940305

real    0m6.238s
```

Comment: To be fair compare apples to apples: compare grep w/o -c piped through wc -l to the sed solution, but I expect sed would still be slower.

Comment: yeah, I had included `sed` only because it was tagged by OP.. sed isn't the tool to use for arithmetic.. and I was actually surprised when I checked grep + LC_ALL=C today which prompted the edit..