# Count the number of rows with a string occurring n times in multiple columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have several hundred text files consisting each of five tab delimited columns.  The first column contains an index and the following four the count of occurrences. Now I would like to count the number of rows that contain 3 columns with 0 (i.e. 7 rows in the example below).

```
1   0   0   0   9
2   0   9   0   0
3   10  0   0   0
4   0   10  4   0
5   0   0   0   10
6   0   0   0   10
7   0   0   0   10
8   0   10  0   0
9   5   0   5   0
```

I can code this as a loop in R, but as the original files each contain 60+ million rows, I wonder if there is no workaround with awk or sed and wc -l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/\t0\>/&/3;t;d' file  | wc -l
```

As pointed out by Isaac, if we want to count exact 3 then do this :

```
sed -n 's/\t0\>//4;t;s//&/3p' file | wc -l
```

Comment: This counts lines with 3 **or more** zeros.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this in `awk`:

```
awk '{ 
       k=0; 
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ 
         if($i == 0){
             k++
         }
       }
       if(k==3){
         tot++
       }
      }
      END{
          print tot
      }' file
```

And also with (GNU) `sed` and `wc`:

```
$ sed -nE '/\b0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0\b/p' file | wc -l
7
```

But, personally, I would do in in perl instead:

```
$ perl -ale '$tot++ if (grep{$_ == 0 } @F) == 3 }{ print $tot' file 
7
```

Or, the slightly less condensed:

```
$ perl -ale 'if( (grep{$_ == 0 } @F) == 3 ){
                  $tot++ 
              }
              END{
                  print $tot
              }' file 
7
```

And the same thing, for the  golfers among you:

```
$ perl -ale '(grep{$_==0}@F)==3&&$t++}{print$t' file
7
```

#### Explanation

- `-ale`: `-a` makes perl behave like awk. It will read each line of the input file and split it on whitespace into the array `@F`. The `-l` adds a `\n` to each call of `print` and removes trailing newlines from the input and the `-e` is the script that should be applied to each line of input.
- `$tot++ if (grep{$_ == 0 } @F) == 3` : increment `$tot` by one, for every time where there are exactly 3 fields that are `0`. Since the 1st field starts from 1, we know it will never be 0 so we don't need to exclude it.
- `}{`: this is just a shorthand way of writing `END{}`, of giving a block of code that will be executed after the file has been processed. So, `}{ print $tot` will print the total number of lines with exactly three fields with a value of `0`.

Comment: The sed solution counts lines with 3 **or more** zeros.

Comment: The perl solution treats a field with a letter (a,b,etc.) as a variable which value is what is tested.

Comment: @Isaac yes, the sed counts 3 or more, but since the OP stated that the file only has five fields, the first is an index (starting at 1) and the last is the sum of fields 2,3 and 4, finding three 0s is sufficient. And yes, again, the perl does that, but why is it a problem? We know the file only has numerical values, and even if it doesn't, the match will simply fail, as it should.

Comment: No, wait, why would it treat a letter any differently? It performs arithmetic comparison, yes, but all fields are treated as variables.

Comment: The title asks for an `n` solution.  limiting the answer to precisely 3 zeros and assuming the first one is never zero doesn't look like a general (for `n`) solution.

Comment: Add a line like `abc 0 0 3 4` or `++2 0 0 2 3` or `0x3 0 2 0 7` or `!4 0 0 3 5` and then try: `perl -ale 'print if (grep{$_ == 0 } @F) == 3' file`. You will see the effect.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU grep` or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```
$ LC_ALL=C grep -c $'\t''0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0\b' ip.txt 
7

$ rg -c '\t0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0\b' ip.txt
7
```

where `$'\t'` will match tab character, thus working even if first column is `0`.

Sample run with large file:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' ip.txt > f1
$ du -h f1
92M f1

$ time LC_ALL=C grep -c $'\t''0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0\b' f1 > f2
real    0m0.416s

$ time rg -c '\t0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0\b' f1 > f3  
real    0m1.271s

$ time LC_ALL=C awk 'gsub(/\t0/,"")==3{c++} END{print c+0}' f1 > f4
real    0m8.645s

$ time perl -ale '$tot++ if (grep{$_ == 0 } @F) == 3 }{ print $tot' f1 > f5
real    0m14.349s

$ time LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/\t0\>//4;t;s//&/3p' f1 | wc -l > f6
real    0m14.075s
$ time LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/\t0\>/&/3p' f1 | wc -l > f8    
real    0m6.772s

$ time LC_ALL=C awk '{ 
       k=0; 
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ 
         if($i == 0){
             k++
         }
       }
       if(k==3){
         tot++
       }
      }
      END{
          print tot
      }' f1 > f7 
real    0m10.675s
```

Remove `LC_ALL=C` if file can contain non-ASCII characters. `ripgrep` is usually faster than `GNU grep` but in test run `GNU grep` was faster. As per `ripgrep`'s author, `(?-u:\b)` can be used to avoid unicode word boundary, but that resulted in similar time for above case.

Comment: Why are you adding the `LC_ALL`, is collation relevant here? The `\b` shouldn't be affected by the locale, what am I missing?

Comment: @terdon I'm aiming for speed here as OP mentions `original files each contain 60+ million rows`

Comment: OK, so how does LC_ALL improve speed in this case? I am not saying you're wrong, I'm sure you're right, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: I'm trying to find a Q&A where Stéphane Chazelas explains how it speeds up.. till then, here's one where `grep` was much faster with `LC_ALL=C` [Counting the number of lines having a number greater than 100](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312297/counting-the-number-of-lines-having-a-number-greater-than-100/312330#312330)

Comment: Not able to find other than [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do/87763#87763), but as far as I understand, the speed benefit it because `LC_ALL=C` would mean characters are all single bytes only (search space is short)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But I bet the reason is that in that case you were using character classes (`[0-9]` etc.) and those are indeed affected by the order of collation. I doubt it would make a difference in this case. I'll make some fake files and test though.

Comment: I just tried this: `perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' ip.txt > f1` and `time grep -wc '0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0' f1 > f2` takes about `0m9.994s` whereas `time LC_ALL=C grep -wc '0\b.*\b0\b.*\b0' f1 > f2` takes about `0m0.449s`

Comment: Well, time  for me to ask a question then! Thanks :)

Comment: You can use non-Unicode word boundaries in ripgrep with `(?-u:\b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\t0/,"")==3{c++} END{print c+0}' file
7
```

Comment: @Isaaec `/[ \t]+/` would recognize spaces as the separator in any awk but then you could get failures if any of the tab-separated fields contains blanks (e.g. a field that's `foo 0 bar`) so it's just not worth it - the OP said the fields are tab-separated so we should just believe them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl to count the number of lines which see a zero surrounded on the  left by a TAB and to the right by a word boundary, three times. In the end print the line count of such lines.

```
perl -lne '$c += 3 == (() = /\t0\b/g)}{print $c' file
7
```

Another way to do it is by looking at the fields:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '$c++ if 3 == grep ! $_, @F[1..$#F]}{print $c' file
```

Yet another way is to use the `s///` command in a scalar context:

```
perl -lne '$c += s/\t0\b//g == 3}{print $c' file
```

We use Gnu awk to do this:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  {
      gsub(FS, FS FS)
      $0 = $0 FS
      if ($0 != gensub(FS"0"FS, "", 3, $0))  ++c
  }
  END{print c}
' file
```

Gnu grep can also help you:

```
grep -cP '(.*\t0\b.*){3}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`solution

```
awk '{x=$0; if(gsub(/\y0\y/, "", x) == 3) y++}; END{print y+0}' file
```

This assumes the index column never contains a `0`.
We set a variable `x` to `$0`, and then replace a `0` surrounded by word boundaries with an empty string via the `gsub` call. Since `gsub` returns the number of replacements made, we increment `y` if return value equals 3

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to match exactly n zeros (not more) with (GNU) sed:

```
$ i=3;               # use the n value wanted.
$ sed -E 's/\<0\>/&/'"$i"';Ta;{s//&/'"$((i+1))"';T};:a;d' file | wc -l
7
```

Explanation

```
i=3                  # define the count of the regex to match.
sed -E               # use extended regexes. reduce the need of `\`.
/\<0\>/              # match a zero (0) surrounded by whitespace.
s/\<0\>/&/           # replace zeros with themselves (detect that they exist)
'"$i"'               # count how many zeros to change.
Ta                   # branch to label `a` (delete line) if
                     # there were less than `i` zeros
{s//&/'"$((i+1))"'   # replace again but now i+1 zeros
T                    # branch to print if there are no more zeros than `i`.
:a;d                 # label to delete line (and catch any other line).
```

The equivalent with (GNU) awk is even simpler (gsub counts exactly how many zeros were replaced).

```
$ awk -vn=3 'gsub(/\<0\>/,"&")==3{c++}END{print c+0}' file
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E '(\<0\>.*){3}' file | wc -l
       7
```

The pattern `\<0\>` will match a lone digit `0`.  The full pattern matches any line that has *at least* three lone zeros.

Te only count lines that contain *exactly* three zeros, not four, remove any line that contains four or more zeros:

```
grep -E '(\<0\>.*){3}' file | grep -v -E '(\<0\>.*){4,}' | wc -l
```